# Loop through multidimensional dictionary and calculate

Tags: python, for-loop

There must be a question about this, but I can't find.

I have a dictionary like this:

```
data = {
    "Jan": {
        "2017-01-01 00:00:00": {
            "001": 10,
            "002": 20,
            "003": 30
        },
        "2017-01-01 01:00:00": {
            "001": 20,
            "002": 40,
            "003": 50
        },
        "2017-01-01 02:00:00": {
            "001": 90,
            "002": 50,
            "003": 60
        }
    }
}
```

I want to loop through the dictionary and calculate the cumulative point, altering the dictionary if possible. For example, for `001` it would be

```
data["Jan"]["2017-01-01 00:00:00"]["001"] == 10
data["Jan"]["2017-01-01 01:00:00"]["001"] == 30
data["Jan"]["2017-01-01 02:00:00"]["001"] == 120
```

I don't want to get the final cumulative sum, I want the relative.

Right now I have this code:

```
import copy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

copydata = copy.deepcopy(data)
# I made a copy because I have an if statement and Python was
  complaining that the dictionary changed size during iteration

for i, month in enumerate(copydata):
    for dt in copydata[month]:
        for user in copydata[month][dt]:
            current_datetime = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
            cumulativepoints=data[month][dt][user] # getting the current hour's points. Since the loop is in random order, it can start at any time
            if current_datetime.hour > 0: # if the hour is 0 then it's the first hour and I don't need to calculate anything
                for x in range(1, current_datetime.hour+1): # starting at 01:00:00 till the current_datetime.hour plus one to count itself
                    past_time = current_datetime - timedelta(hours=x)
                    past_time = past_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
                    if data[month][past_time]:
                        cumulativepoints += data[month][past_time][user]
                    data[month][past_time][user] = cumulativepoints # <--- the error happens here
```

But at that line `data[month][past_time][user] = cumulativepoints`, Python throws an error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

I'm pretty sure this code is a lot more complicated than it should be. But that is the result of many adaptations due to many error messages.

Comment: A `dict` is not going to be a good data-structure for this, it isn't ordered, and you are going to iterate the keys in random-order.  But the order is crucial for what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: @rlcabral, I'm receiving no errors of any kind in Python 2.7.3. Assuming there is an issue, try encapsulating the variable `cumulativepoints` in an `int()` function. Also do the same to the line above with `data[month][past_time][user]`. I'm getting the feeling that you're accidentally passing a string instead of an integer.

Comment: @SirJames, Same error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, what would be a better data-structure? I have the full data in a CSV file, so I can easily read it again creating a different data-structure.

Comment: Well, since order is important, some sort of nested list, maybe a list of dicts or list of list. If you want to get fancy, you can used namedtuple's for the records.

Comment: you can also use an OrderedDict from the standard library

Comment: Sorry, but I'm lost. I'm trying to load the data again, but I can't see how to create a list of list and easily access each list the way I want.

Comment: @rlcabral, what version of Python are you using? I'm trying to get the same error you are, but I'm not succeeding (it works each time I do what you have listed).

Comment: @SirJames Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Loop through multidimensional dictionary and calculate

You can do it, for instance:

```
def pp_dict():
    for month in data:
        print('month:{}'.format(month))
        for dt in sorted(data[month]):
            print('\tdt:{}'.format(dt))
            for user in sorted(data[month][dt]):
                print('\t\tuser:{}:{}'.format(user, data[month][dt][user]))

def cum_sum(month, user):
    cum_sum = 0
    for dt in sorted(data[month]):
        cum_sum += data[month][dt][user]
        data[month][dt][user] = cum_sum


for user in ['001']:
    cum_sum('Jan', user)

pp_dict()
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> month:Jan
> dt:2017-01-01 00:00:00
>     user:001:10
>     user:002:20
>     user:003:30
> dt:2017-01-01 01:00:00
>     user:001:30
>     user:002:40
>     user:003:50
> dt:2017-01-01 02:00:00
>     user:001:120
>     user:002:50
>     user:003:60
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: The problem with your approach is that it calculates for a single user. I would need to loop through all data calling your function on each user, and it would for sure call the function with the same param multiple times. But for now, I'd say that your answer will have to work for me.

Comment: @rlcabral: Add as many User to the array in `for user in ['001']:`, for example `for user in ['001', '002']:` an so on.